# Getting Integer value from a String using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

These are the strings I have:

```
"test123.00"
"yes50.00"
```

I want to add the 123.00 with 50.00.

How can I do this?

I used the command parseInt() but it displays NaN error in alert box.

This is the code:

```
 str1 = "test123.00";
 str2 = "yes50.00";
 total = parseInt(str1)+parseInt(str2);
 alert(total);
```

Comment: you need to use regexp to filter out non-numbers and then use parseInt()

Comment: Why is php tagged on this question?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

just do this , you need to remove char other than "numeric" and "." form your string will do work for you

```
yourString = yourString.replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' );
```

your final code will be

```
  str1 = "test123.00".replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' );
  str2 = "yes50.00".replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' );
  total = parseInt(str1, 10) + parseInt(str2, 10);
  alert(total);
```

#### Demo

Comment: What if number contains `-`? E.g. `-123.00`

Answer (score 7):

For parseInt to work, your string should have only numerical data. Something like this:

```
 str1 = "123.00";
 str2 = "50.00";
 total = parseInt(str1)+parseInt(str2);
 alert(total);
```

Can you split the string before you start processing them for a total?

Answer (score 2):

```
str1 = "test123.00";
str2 = "yes50.00";
intStr1 = str1.replace(/[A-Za-z$-]/g, "");
intStr2 = str2.replace(/[A-Za-z$-]/g, "");
total = parseInt(intStr1)+parseInt(intStr2);

alert(total);
```

working [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fosterz/v8rBG/)

Answer (score -2):

Is this logically possible??.. I guess the approach that you must take is this way :

```
Str1 ="test123.00"
Str2 ="yes50.00"
```

This will be impossible to tackle unless you have delimiter in between `test` and `123.00`

```
eg: Str1 = "test-123.00"
```

Then you can split this way

```
Str2 = Str1.split("-");
```

This will return you an array of words split with "-"

Then you can do `parseFloat(Str2[1])` to get the floating value i.e `123.00`

Comment: It can do without delimiter.